# Laravel 4.2 subdomain route-parameter

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes, subdomain

i've setup some subdomains on my localhost using `xampp`.
this is my subdomain-routes:

```
    Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.localhost'], function(){
    Route::get('home',                array('as'=>'sub.home',         'uses'=>'SubdomainController@home')
    Route::get('gallery/{id}',     array('as'=>'sub.gallery',        'uses'=>'SubdomainController@gallery'));
});
```

These are my links:

```
{{ URL::route('sub.home', array($subdomain)) }}
{{ URL::route('sub.gallery', array($subdomain,2)) }}
```

The "home-route" works as expected, but whatever i do, the gallery-route parameter "2" is not passed to the method, instead it shows the name of the subdomain.

Can anyone point my to the right direction.

**E D I T**
when i add $subdomain to the method, i get the correct $id.
Now the new question is how to do this without injecting the subdomain-param to every method.

```
public function gallery($subdomain, $id) {
    die($id);//output is now "2"
}
```

Comment: Did you try `{{ URL::route('sub.gallery', ['subdomain'=>$subdomain,'id'=>2]) }}` ?

Comment: I did, but didnt change a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aswering your first question: you should use variable in your action, example [from Laravel sub-domain official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing):

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Answering your second question: you could try to hardcode you subdomain:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'something.localhost'], function(){
```

If you use variable like `{subdomain}`, you must catch it in action anyway.

Comment: Sorry, i dont really get it, can you give me an example how a named route has to be written using the account and id parameter.

Comment: You route is ok, it should work. And your action should catch both `$account` and `$id` (vars are from my example).

Comment: so i have to put $subdomain to every controller-action? ie:public function gallery($subdomain, $id) { ...} ? I cant believe that ther's no smarter way to handle this.

Comment: Yes, you must do it, because route transports two agruments.